# How can I export ArcScene animation to .mov quicktime file?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, export, animation, arcscene

ArcGIS 10 documentation says that **an animation can be exported to either .avi or .mov (quicktime)**.  I only see the .avi option in my drop-down list?  What am I missing.
[image]

**EDIT: Quicktime is installed on my computer**

Comment: change filename to 3.mov for other options - note: For high-quality videos with sharp text and data, use a codec that does not apply a lossy compression. For example, if exporting to AVI, you can use Full Frames (Uncompressed) when choosing the codec on the Video Compression dialog box. The lesser the lossy compression, the larger the size of the output video. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Tips_for_creating_high_quality_videos/000900000062000000/

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz - that's what I normally do but uncompressed AVI is too jerky even after increasing speed in a movie editor and exporting to a lossy format.  Just trying other alternatives.

Comment: @ Jakub - Is purchasing a software that's specialized for this type of thing (and exports to different formats) an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the Quicktime codecs.

You can either [download and install quicktime from Apple](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/).

Or if you don't want all the junk that Apple bundle together, there's the [QuickTime Alternative](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/quicktime_alternative.htm) - though there's no guaranteeing that ArcGIS will pick that up.

(See also, very bottom of - http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/doc/03dc974a-5681-4aec-b983-f6b66468a309.htm )

**Alternatively: Known bug**

See: http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDYzMTYz - its been reported as a bug in ArcGIS 10. Apparently one that's been open for a long time.

Comment: THanks @GIS-Jonathan; I have Quicktime installed so I assumed the codecs were installed automatically. I will download the latest and try again.

Comment: Should work according to this page too - http://www.gsd.harvard.edu/gis/manual/globetrouble/index.htm

Comment: Definitely doesn't work for me. I uninstalled Quicktime then downloaded and installed newest version and I still only have the option to export to AVI or Sequential Images

Comment: @Jakub - updated by answer - it may be a result of a known bug.

Comment: LOL!!! Alternative solution = use 9.3.1 to export your video to .mov.  Love that one!  THanks Jonathan.

Answer (score 1):

i wonder that do you have quicktime installed on your machine? maybe ArcScene cant communicate without quicktime..

i guess that i have encountered such a problem in the adobe after effects too. you can try to use QuickTime Alternative 3.2.2 [here](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/QuickTime_Alternative.htm).

i hope it helps you...